# Setting up websocket listener inside of Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, websocket, vue-component

I've created a component which will be used multiple times on the site and represents a row of a table.

Now I want each instance of this component to update itself according to the messages received via websocket.

I tried to register an `onmessage` listener in the `created()` method of the component, but it doesn't seem to work like this. `created()` gets called for each row of the table, but the listener doesn't show any effect.

When I register the listener in my "main" App.vue it's working. But I'd like it in my component so I have easy access to it's properties.

Can you give me some hints what I'm doing wrong?

**Here's a sample of my component:**

```js
<template>
<div class="feed-item">
  <div class="feed-element">{{feed.name}}</div>
  <div class="feed-element">{{feed.idle}}</div>
  <div class="feed-element">{{feed.unseen}}</div>
  <div class="feed-element">{{feed.last_message}}</div>
  <div class="feed-element">{{feed.page}}</div>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
/* ... */
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'feedItem',
    props: {feed: Object},
    created () {
      this.$options.sockets.onmessage = (data) => console.log(data)
    },
  }
</script>
```

**And I loaded `vue-native-websocket` im my main.js:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'


Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://127.0.0.1:9000', {
  format: 'json',
  // store: store,
  reconnection: true,
  reconnectionDelay: 1000
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
})
```

Comment: Maybe event bus will help? https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/. `$emit` where it works (in you main App.vue) and `$on` in every other component.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have a similar challenge I don't really understand where to put the listener. It's not super clear for me in the documentation.